# How to Export Multiple Collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, export

How to Export multiple collections in one shot in mongoDB because i want to export all parameter from one server and import to another server ?

Answer (score 0):

Import & Export MongoDB data using Command

1. Open the System Command
2. Go to below location in command. Type below query and press enter
   cd “C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin”
3. To Export the data, type below command
   mongodump -d  -o 
   for ex- mongodump -d NJNG_DB -o c:\temp\copy.json

Once the data exported successfully, you can see the folder in your given output path

4. To Import the data, type below command
   mongorestore --db  <Output Path Location{DataBaseName}>
   for ex- mongorestore –db NJNG_DB c:\temp\copy.json\NJNG_DB